# ARM, Branch with link, BL vs MOV, B

Tags: assembly, branch

Is there any difference between:

```
bl label
```

and

```
mov r14, r15
b label
```

Other than convenience?

(I'm using a Raspberry Pi, so r15 is the current address + 8, due to the pipeline)

Comment: why wouldnt you use bl?  it works both arm and thumb

Comment: I am, but I want to be certain their equivalent do when I say they are someone (like my lecturer) doesn't say "but actually..."

Comment: yes, functionally they are the same.  the pc is two instructions ahead, and loading it into r14 then branching is functionally the same as bl which loads the next instruction address into r14 then branches.  See the pseudo code for the particular architecture/core to see if there are any bl vs b nuances independent of r14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be relevant for what you are doing, but there is a difference: the `mov + b` method has different timing than the simpler `bl`. `mov` with a destination that is not PC takes 1 cycle. `bl` and `b` both take the same number of cycles (depends on branch prediction).

So, using

```
mov r14, r15
b label
```

takes one cycle longer than

```
bl label
```

This could be important in an embedded application with strict timing requirements. `bl label` is clearer and should be used, and if timing is an issue, `nop + bl` would be more clear than `mov + b`.

References: [Cycle counts if destination is not the PC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/ch15s03s02.html), [Branches](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360e/ch15s03s02.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use B instead of BL, the branch type inside branch monitor will not consider it as a call, making it harder for you analyze what the software is going on.